# Best way to determine if my app was updated

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, xamarin.ios

I have an IOS app, and each time it is updated I want to do some house cleaning. What is the best way to determine if an IOS app has been updated?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this more?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest way may be to get the current version, compare the version to a saved version (if there is one), perform clean up if necessary, save the new version. Here are examples on retrieving and storing version info for comparison.

```
//Getting the application version
NSString *version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"]

//Retrieving the saved application version
NSString *savedVersion = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"versionkey"];

//Saving the version
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:version forKey:@"versionkey"];
```

And if you are wondering how to compare versions here is an example using the `NSNumericSearch` compare option: http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=148

Answer (score 1):

You could store the "last seen" version number in a database table, then on startup compare that value against the bundle version number. Get this by doing:

```
NSString* version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
```

If the current version is greater than the "last seen" version, perform your house cleaning, then update the "last seen" version in the database table to the current bundle version.

Answer (score 1):

Joe's way is completely perfect. Just to help those out heres a little help if you never set a version in defaults on a previous version or if you want to check if current version matches version saved.

```
//Getting the application version
NSString *version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"]
//Retrieving the saved application version
NSString *savedVersion = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"versionkey"];

if (version == nil || [version isEqualToString:savedVersion]){
//Saving the version
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:version forKey:@"versionkey"];
}
```